# Delete a directory, but preserve all of its contents including (subdirectory and files)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Can you please help me out with this scenario, where i want to delete a directory but keep all of its contents. The thing is, there is this rogue/ vague sub-folder in exports i receive and, i have to go to this vague sub-folder and move all of its contents to its parent directory and delete this rogue folder. I have tried writing a few recursive functions but it is all acting weird.

Input
Folder-1 --> Sub-Folder-1 --> Rogue-Folder --> Sub-Folder --> Files

Output
Folder-1 --> Sub-Folder-1 --> Sub-Folder --> Files

Any suggestions/ideas?

Regards

Comment: Do the folders always have the same names? Is ```Rogue-Folder``` always empty except for ```Sub-Folder```?

Comment: Rogue-Folder name is fixed, Yes, it is always empty except the sub-folder, the subfolder then has some files

Comment: _but it is all acting weird_ -- What does this mean?  Please show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually my sister would do something like that for me using shell scripts, but I decided to try a minimal C# code, but it ended up being more elaborate than expected. Error handling is not optimal, and I have not tested stress scenarios... in fact, I haven't tested it that much. It all seems to be working as expected

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace EliminateRogueFolder
{
    class Program
    {
        static string _rogueName = null;

        public static void Main (string [] args)
        {
            Console.SetWindowSize(Math.Max(Console.WindowWidth + 45, 125), Console.WindowHeight);

            Console.WriteLine($"** Rogue Folder Eliminator **{Environment.NewLine}");

            try
            {
                int counter = 0;

                string path = "";

                if (args.Length == 0)
                {
                    printUsage();
                    Environment.Exit(-1);
                }
                if(args[0].ToLower() == "-r")
                {
                    if (args.Length >= 3)
                    {
                        _rogueName = args [1];
                        counter = 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printUsage();
                        Environment.Exit(-1);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = counter; i < args.Length; ++i)
                {
                    path = args [i];
                    path = path.Replace('\\', '/');

                    removeRogueFolder(path);
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}Execution Ended Successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\n\n\nERROR:\n{e.Message}\n\n");
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
        }

        static void removeRogueFolder(string path)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}FIXING:{Environment.NewLine}{path}");

            List<string> folders = path.TrimEnd('/', ' ').Split('/').ToList();
            string lastFolder = folders.Last();

            folders.RemoveAt(folders.Count - 1);
            if (_rogueName != null && folders.Last() != _rogueName)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{_rogueName} not found in{Environment.NewLine}{path}{Environment.NewLine}Skipping");
                return;
            }

            string rogueFolder = Path.Combine(folders.ToArray());
            rogueFolder = rogueFolder.Replace('\\', '/');

            folders.RemoveAt(folders.Count - 1);
            string destinationFolder = Path.Combine(folders.ToArray());
            destinationFolder = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, lastFolder);
            destinationFolder = destinationFolder.Replace('\\', '/');

            moveFolder(source: path, destination: destinationFolder);

            if (!isFolderEmpty(rogueFolder))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{rogueFolder} is not Empty!{Environment.NewLine}Skipping");
                return;
            }

            deleteFolder(rogueFolder);

            Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}FIXED:{Environment.NewLine}{path}");
        }

        static void moveFolder(string source, string destination)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MOVING:{Environment.NewLine}{source}{Environment.NewLine}TO{Environment.NewLine}{destination}");
            Directory.Move(source, destination);
        }

        static void deleteFolder(string path)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DELETING:{Environment.NewLine}{path}");
            Directory.Delete(path);
        }

        static bool isFolderEmpty (string path) => Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Count() == 0;

        static void printUsage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("USAGE: EliminateRogueFolder.exe \"[path-to-folder]\"");
            Console.WriteLine("EXAMPLE: EliminateRogueFolder.exe \"C:/MyProjects/Resources/RogueFolder/Images\"");
            Console.WriteLine("This will copy the folder C:/MyProjects/Resources/RogueFolder/Images");
            Console.WriteLine("to the C:/MyProjects/Resources folder");
            Console.WriteLine("and delete C:/MyProjects/Resources/RogueFolder.");
            Console.WriteLine("The result will be C:/MyProjects/Resources/Images.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You can specify the name of the rogue folder by suplying the parameters -r \"[rogue-folder-name]\" as first parameters");
            Console.WriteLine("If the penultimate folder in [path-to-folder] is not equal to [rogue-folder-name], [path-to-folder] is not changed at all");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You can specicify more than one [path-to-folder] parameters, separated by spaces, the program will try to fix all paths");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("(Note that, as a safety mechanism, RogueFolder will not be deleted if it contains any other files)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts you put into this. Was helpful. I also found a rather shorter way of doing it all, where in you fetch all the directory paths, and the file paths, then remove the rogue folder name from each of these paths and create directories and move files.